# Can you colour the leading tip of the triangles in my plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, symbols

I am plotting the wind speed and direction for the UK at particular locations. What I am wondering, is there a way to colour the leading tip of the triangles to make the direction of the wind more apparent?

My code for plotting this is:

```
payload_user={'maddison.newman@example.com': {'lat': '51.45', 'lon': '-2.59'},'mandy.larson@example.com': {'lat': '52.06', 'lon': '-2.82'}}
m.plot(y=float(payload_user[email_user]['lat']),x=float(payload_user[email_user]['lon']),marker=(3,0,wind_direction_deg),color = col, markersize=7 )
                    plt.title("Wind speed and Direction in the UK for specific users")
                    plt.xlabel('Longitude')
                    plt.ylabel("Latitude")
```

Map of the UK with windspeed and direction:

[image: Map of the UK with windspeed and direction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any reasonably easy way to colorize part of a marker differently than the rest of the marker. For showing direction, however, I could imagine that using a non-equilateral, but isosceles triangle, makes sense.

[image]

One way to achieve such a triangle is to use the `marker=verts` notation, where `verts` are the vertices of the polygon to be used as marker.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_arrow(angle):
    a = np.deg2rad(angle)
    ar = np.array([[-.25,-.5],[.25,-.5],[0,.5],[-.25,-.5]]).T
    rot = np.array([[np.cos(a),np.sin(a)],[-np.sin(a),np.cos(a)]])
    return np.dot(rot,ar).T

for i, angle in enumerate([0,45,60,-36]):
    plt.plot(i/10.,0.6,marker=get_arrow(angle), ms=30)

plt.show()
```

[image]